How to extract encrypted key and encrypted content from a CMS EnvelopedData object in Java?
I am working with CMS (Cryptographic Message Syntax) envelopes in Java and need to extract the encrypted key and encrypted content from a CMSEnvelopedData object using the BouncyCastle library. Specifically, I want to extract these components from the data1 byte array after encryption.
I am using the following code to encrypt the data, and I want to extract the encrypted key and content separately.
Encryption code:
public class Encryption {

    static String certificatePath = "C:\\Users\\PSAD07564\\Desktop\\Peppol\\IVLenght\\peppol.lx.erf01.net.crt";
    private static final String RSA_TRANSFORMATION = "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding";
    private static final String AES_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
    private static final int GCM_TAG_LENGTH = 128;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        // Path to the .key file
        String keyFilePath = "C:\\Users\\PSAD07564\\Desktop\\Peppol\\IVLenght\\peppol.lx.erf01.net.key";

        // Read the private key file
        String keyContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(keyFilePath)));

        // Clean up the key content
        keyContent = keyContent.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                               .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                               .replaceAll("\\s+", ""); // Remove all whitespace

        // Decode the Base64-encoded private key
        byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(keyContent);

        // Generate a PrivateKey instance
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

        String plainText = "AES 256 GCM Testing";

        // Create a CertificateFactory instance
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        // Read the certificate from the file
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(certificatePath);
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(fis);

        CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator cmsEnvelopedDataGenerator = new CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator();
        CMSEnvelopedData data = null;
        cmsEnvelopedDataGenerator.addRecipientInfoGenerator(new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(certificate, rsaesOaepIdentifier())
                .setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME));

        data = cmsEnvelopedDataGenerator.generate(new CMSProcessableByteArray(plainText.getBytes()),
                new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMSAlgorithm.AES256_GCM).setProvider("BC").build());

        byte[] data1 = data.getEncoded();

        System.out.println("Data:");
        System.out.println(data);
        System.out.println(data1);
    }

    private static AlgorithmIdentifier rsaesOaepIdentifier() {
        AlgorithmIdentifier hash = new AlgorithmIdentifier(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha256, DERNull.INSTANCE);
        AlgorithmIdentifier mask = new AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_mgf1, hash);
        AlgorithmIdentifier pSource = new AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_pSpecified, new DEROctetString(new byte[0]));
        return new AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_RSAES_OAEP, new RSAESOAEPparams(hash, mask, pSource));
    }
}

I need to extract the encrypted key and the encrypted content from the data1 byte array (the encoded CMS envelope).
How do I extract these components (encrypted key and encrypted content) separately from the CMSEnvelopedData object generated by the data.getEncoded() method?
